# How do I add a box explaining which line belongs to which function?

Tags: plot, octave

I want to make a plot showing the plots of two different functions. One of them is plotted using a continuous line while the other is drawn using a dashed line. I want to have a box that says something like

```
- - f(x)
----- g(x)
```

to explain which function is drawn with which line. How do I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That box is called a legend in English. https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/legend.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you look at the [documentation on plot annotations](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Plot-Annotations.html).  In your case, the `legend` function is what you're looking for.  See the following example:

```
>> a = [1 2 3 4 5];
>> b = sin(a);c = cos(a);
>> plot(a,b,'--',a,c,'-*')
>> legend('sin(a)','cos(a)')
```

[image: figure showing different plot styles with a legend]